# Accessing contents from a remote plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, plist

Before anyone marks my question as duplicate, let me tell you , that I have gone through all the answers and i could not find a solution.

So here is my question ,

I try to set the userdefaults like servername, serverport , UDID, languagepack and erid as soon as the app launches using a key .

All these variables are set on the server side .

I know I can write a logic to download that plist and access the data , but here , I can write only one app and the server varies for all the different clients that we have .

So when this app is pushed from a server to a device ,that plist is also pushed.

But whenever I try to access the contents, it returns nil and the app crashes(which was working fine with the same logic in objective-c , possibly due to the fact that nil is taken as a value in objective c).

My question is how is this possible because , when a profile is installed in the device , how does the app access the contents without any logic written in the code .

And this is the **plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
<string>InstallApplication;Collection=302</string>
<key>Command</key>
<dict>
    <key>RequestType</key>
    <string>InstallApplication</string>
    <key>ManifestURL</key>
    <string>https://%ServerName%:%ServerPort%/MDM/apprepository/1/appupload/2/2/Manifest.plist</string>
    <key>ManagementFlags</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>ChangeManagementState</key>
    <string>Managed</string>
    <key>Configuration</key>
    <dict>
        <key>ServerName</key>
        <string>%ServerName%</string>
        <key>ServerPort</key>
        <string>%ServerPort%</string>
        <key>UDID</key>
        <string>%udid%</string>
        <key>ErID</key>
        <string>%erid%</string>
        <key>IsLanguagePackEnabled</key>
        <string>%license_pack_enabled%</string>
    </dict>

</dict>
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit : I tried registering the defaults , I tried using DictionaryForKey instead of objectForKey with the key being "com.apple.configuration.managed"  (both the cases make no difference) and my code in swift is

```
let userDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
 if let dict = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey(mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION) {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(dict)
 if let serverName = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERNAMEKEY] as? String{
 }
        if let serverPort = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.SERVERPORTKEY] as? String{
}
        if let UDID = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.UDIDKEY] as? String{
}
        if let languagePack = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.IS_LANG_PACK_ENABLED] as? String{
}
        if let ErID = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.ERIDKEY] as? String{
}
        if let authToken = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.AUTHTOKENKEY] as? String {
 }else {
            authToken = ""
        }


if let scope = dict[mdmiosagent_Constants.SCOPEKEY] as? String {

        } else {
            scope = ""
        }

    }
```

where the constants are declared as

```
  static let SERVERNAMEKEY = "ServerName"
static let SERVERPORTKEY = "ServerPort"
static let ERIDKEY = "ErID"
static let UDIDKEY = "UDID"
static let AUTHTOKENKEY = "authtoken"
static let SCOPEKEY = "SCOPE"
static let MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION = "com.apple.configuration.managed"
static let IS_LANG_PACK_ENABLED = "IsLanguagePackEnabled"
```

Comment: Please show us your code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I tried initialising the dictionary that is used to store the defaults as a NSDictionary instead of [String: AnyObject] and it worked !! Woah , never expected this would be the reason. Thank you all though for providing suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Looking over your code, I don't see a register anywhere. I can't promise anything, but I would at least try changing:

```
let userDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

to:

```
let userDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(userDefaults)
```

You will also want to test to be sure that you have loaded it properly:

```
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Defaults", ofType: "plist")
        , defaults = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:path) as? [String : AnyObject] {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(defaults)
```

Comment: Ok, a step back. Does  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Defaults", ofType: "plist") return a value or nil? Is that the right name for the defaults file? Look in the bundle.

Comment: Ok, so when you `let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("install profile", ofType: "plist")` you get a value?

Comment: My question remains: are you actually getting a file in your bundle, and is that file in the place you expect and have the name you expect? You won't read many defaults from a non-existant file :-) Suggestion: make an app that does nothing except run that line and print the results in an NSTextField. Push that from your server to the iOS device and see if you can find the bundle.